# How do I add a duplicate div above a button rather than below

Tags: jquery, html

I would like to add the div with the id name of bakkant above  the 'addrow' button rather than below that.   Also for some reason, while it works perfectly fine in Jsfiddle, the rows are displaying then immediatedly disappearing in practice).  What is the best way to do so?   https://jsfiddle.net/j3xazjak/3/

```
        <div class="shape" id="plan4_shape">
            <span class="bakkant">
            <input class="measures" id="plan4_width" placeholder="mm"/><span class="times"> &times;</span> <input class="measures" id="plan4_width" placeholder="mm"/>
             </span>
            <span class="bakkant" id="bakkant">
            <input class="measures" id="plan4_width" placeholder="mm"/><span class="times"> &times;</span> <input class="measures" id="plan4_width" placeholder="mm"/><button class="close" value="close1">&times;</button>
            </span>
            <button name="add_row" class="addrow" id="addrow4" onClick="addrow()">Add row</button>
        </div>
```

Jquery

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
document.getElementById('addrow4').onclick = duplicate;

var i = 0;
var original = document.getElementById('bakkant');

function duplicate() {

    var clone = original.cloneNode(true);
  clone.id = "bakkant" + ++i; 
  original.parentNode.appendChild(clone);

}
/* var clone = original.cloneNode(true); // "deep" clone
    clone.id = "duplicetor" + ++i; // there can only be one element with an ID
    original.parentNode.appendChild(clone);
    */
  /*  jQuery('.four').before('<div class="addme">Add Me!</div>'); */
    });
```

Comment: Please can you include your jsFiddle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use insertBefore

```
original.parentNode.insertBefore(clone, original);
```